# How to add Additional Properties to a Class without inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm having a Class `MobileInfo`

```
public class MobileInfo
{
    public string MobileName { get; set; }
    public string MobileOS { get; set; }
}
```

I need to add one more property

```
public string MobileModel { get; set; }
```

I implemented the `Model` class in more-than 100 class files in my main project and the base class `MobileInfo` is in Remote Server. I need to add the Property without inheritance and without modification of the base class.

> Note: Don't Create a Derived Class to add this Property, because I
>   can't able to change the base class instance. I'm having permission to
>   access the instance and I can add the property without touching the
>   base class.

Comment: What do you mean by "I implemented the Model class in more-than 100 class files"? Do you have 100+ descendants of `MobileInfo`? Suppose, you have added desired property. How do you plan to set its value?

Comment: Why exactly are you not allowed to interhit the class?

Comment: As `MobileInfo` is laying on remote server, I suppose that you has local implementation of this class, which mapped to `MobileInfo` and your 100+ descendants are inherit from local base class. Why can not you add property to local base class?

Comment: you want to change the class without changing its code, right? I don't think it's possible, or makes much sense for that matter. what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @slawekwin - Most Probably you are right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx)

```
var curPhone = new MobileInfo();
        curPhone.MobileName = "iphone";
        curPhone.MobileOS = "ios";
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(MobileInfo), new simpleAttribute());
        AttributeCollection collection = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(curPhone);
        simpleAttribute attr = ((simpleAttribute)collection[typeof(simpleAttribute)]);
        if (attr != null)
        {
            attr.MobileModul = "s6";
            //MessageBox.Show(attr.MobileModul);
        }   

    }

    public class simpleAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string MobileModul { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add property for class without changing it code.

With `System.Reflection.Emit` methods you can create dynamic assembly, which will copy your `MobileInfo` and whole hierarchy of descendant classes. See [creating type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.createtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_3) and [method for set parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zfbcfc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). After what you can add required property to **generated** copy of `MobileInfo`. Next you should configure abstract factory, which will return generated type when you are querying your types.

But it's rather difficult. I strongly recommend to remake your project architecture. As `MobileInfo` is on the remote server, so your local data model should have a copy of `MobileInfo` and should not inherit remote `MobileInfo`, additionally, you should have methods for mapping from remote server data model objects to local. So, you can do with your local `MobileInfo` anything what you want.